# Neo4j query really slow when using collect(distinct) and order by

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm a novice in Neo4j right now

database schema:

[image]
Currently i'm trying to find all (developer|company|publisher) nodes with it's related platform's Games Nodes in my data:

1. find a Game node where the game belong to a Platform node
2. Game node must have a relationship with a Genre node contains a certain string, Game.deleted property must not be Null
3. we have relationships of Platform -- Game, (Developer|Company|Publisher)-[r:DEVELOPED_BY|PUBLISHED_BY] - Game --> Genre
4. query will return (Developer|Company|Publisher) with it's related Game node

So i have the following query:

```
MATCH (p:Platform)--(g:Game),(d)-[r:DEVELOPED_BY|PUBLISHED_BY]-(g)-->(ge:Genre)                    
WHERE ge.id CONTAINS 'Filtered' AND p.id = 'PS5' AND g.deleted is null                    
RETURN g, collect(DISTINCT d) as d ORDER BY g.title DESC SKIP 0 LIMIT 100
```

the return row contain 2 columns, games and it's d(developer|publisher|company) for examples:

[image]

**PROBLEM**:
the query run really slow (15~30sec depend on platform) even if i indexed all the properties (Game.id), (Platform.id)

> Started streaming 100 records after 312 ms and completed after 15743
> ms.

Profile:

[image]

My data has hundred thousands of Game node. How do i improve the query? i see that these 2 have million of DB hits

[image]

**UPDATES**:

After removing the contains query and changed to using regex

```
=~ "Filtered.*"
```

The query speed improved significantly, down to only 2000ms(2 secs) down from 15743ms(15 secs). I still don't understand why CONTAINS slow down the query by so much, even though i already indexed the field with text index type

the above query slow down by alot if i query on around 200000 game nodes, which still doesn't solve my problem

changing the query to this with the large game node dataset speed up the query to just under 1 second

```
MATCH (p:Platform)--(g:Game),(d)-[r:DEVELOPED_BY|PUBLISHED_BY]-(g)-->(ge:Genre)                    
    WHERE ge.id CONTAINS 'Filtered' AND p.id = 'PS5' AND g.deleted is null                    
    RETURN g, d LIMIT 100
```

why is collect(distinct d) and order by took so much time? how can i solve this?

Comment: Adding more relationship types and directions in your query would probably be a good start

Comment: @TomažBratanič i checked and seem like the CONTAINS make the query really slow, i tried using regex instead with =~ 'Filtered.*' and it down to 1 second of query time. Is there a reason why? because i also indexed the genre.id field to both fulltext and text with no improvement

Comment: As you can see from the profiler, it only uses genre.id index... Indexes are used to find an entry point to the graph and that's more or less about it.

The thing is that in Browser you are returning nodes... and it takes some time for Browser to visualize nodes. Perhaps you also have "Connect result nodes" option, which introduces even more overhead. I would try the same query in a scripting language, where there is not viz overhead and compare that

Comment: @TomažBratanič actually in neo4j browser the query time can be show in the code sidebar of the query `Started streaming 100 records after 12 ms and completed after 476 ms.` or any other tab other than the graph sidebar tab